# bq command-line tool: query fails when text includes " > " or " < "

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm having problems using the bq command-line tool to run queries that contain a > or < symbol.

The first two examples below show that when I try to select rows from a table where id > 300 nothing is returned, yet when I select for id=301 I get a result.

The second two examples show that when I try to select rows where id < 300 I get a syntax error, but when I select for id=299 I get a result.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Many thanks,

Steve

C:\Users\stephen.caruana>bq query "SELECT sk_id from test.test_1 WHERE id > 300 LIMIT 5"
Waiting on bqjob_r56794831_000001585450df31_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE

C:\Users\stephen.caruana>bq query "SELECT sk_id from test.test_1 WHERE id = 301 LIMIT 5"
Waiting on bqjob_r03e25be0_0000015854521a94_1 ... (3s) Current status: DONE
+-------+
| sk_id |
+-------+
|   301 |
+-------+

C:\Users\stephen.caruana>bq query "SELECT sk_id from test.test_1 WHERE id < 300 LIMIT 5"
Waiting on bqjob_r1615cc38_000001585451837a_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
Error in query string: Error processing job
'itg-creator-lgi-ecrm:bqjob_r1615cc38_000001585451837a_1': WHERE clause is not a
boolean expression (found int64)

C:\Users\stephen.caruana>bq query "SELECT sk_id from test.test_1 WHERE id = 299 LIMIT 5"
Waiting on bqjob_r7e6824a9_000001585452ba30_1 ... (2s) Current status: DONE
+-------+
| sk_id |
+-------+
|   299 |
+-------+

Comment: I should add that the queries that fail in the command-line tool all work perfectly well in the web UI

Comment: Check your terminal settings and xterm. I just tried this and it works as desired. Try to escape it with \ and see if works.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Windows command prompt issue. You need to escape the ">" and "<" symbols with "^", otherwise command prompt thinks it's a redirect of the output. So your command should look like

`bq query "SELECT sk_id from test.test_1 WHERE id ^> 300 LIMIT 5"`