# powershell bq query distorts the SQL statement (drops a section following > sign)

Tags: powershell, google-bigquery, gcloud

I am running the following command from a powershell using Cloud SDK to create a scheduled query.

```
$query = "SELECT projectId as ProjectId, datasetId as DataSet, SUM(queryCostInUSD) as TotalCostInDollars, MIN(queryCostInUSD) as LeastExpensiveQueryInDollars, MAX(queryCostInUSD) as MostExpensiveQueryInDollars, Count(*) as QueryCount, TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) as StartDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as EndDate FROM ``$MYPROJECTID.$MYPROJECT_MONITORING_DATASET_NAME.$MYPROJECT_MONITORING_VIEW_NAME`` where startTime>=TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) Group by ProjectId, datasetId"

bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --destination_table=$MYPROJECTID`:$MYPROJECT_MONITORING_DATASET_NAME.BigQuery_Daily_Cost --display_name='BigQuery Daily Cost Scheduled Query' --replace=false --append_table --schedule='every 24 hours' $query
```

The scheduled job does get created, but for some reason it is dropping the part after "startTime >". The query ends up like this in the BigQuery GUI:

```
SELECT projectId as ProjectId, datasetId as DataSet, SUM(queryCostInUSD) as TotalCostInDollars, MIN(queryCostInUSD) as LeastExpensiveQueryInDollars, MAX(queryCostInUSD) as MostExpensiveQueryInDollars, Count(*) as QueryCount, TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) as StartDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as EndDate FROM `ingestion-test-prat.Monitoring.BigQuery_JobCompleted_Pricing_View` where startTime , INTERVAL 1 DAY) Group by ProjectId, datasetId
```

Note the missing snippet after "startTime >".

and I get the error "Query error: Syntax error: Unexpected "," at [1:411]".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @vonPryz no it is not. I updated my question.

Comment: I realized that powershell ended up creating a file called "TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()" in my local folder. This has something to do with redirection in powershell https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7. So how do I properly escape > sign in powershell. I am not doing an actual comparison so I can't use -lt as suggested.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the it using the standard escape character e.g. starttime`>TIMESTAMP_SUB ?

Comment: Just to verify that the problem is with the character. Could you try running the query only with `startTime>TIMESTAMP_...` instead of `startTime>=TIMESTAMP_...` ?

Comment: Yes tried both. Didn’t work.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40562412/609290